# MongoDb can't create migration scripts

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a migration script on an existing project with already initialized  `migrate-mongo`. I'm using windows btw.

Here is my problem.
When I try to create a script using this command `migrate-mongo create blacklist_the_beatles`
I get this error.

```
ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\saadb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\migrate-mongo\samples\undefined\migration.js' Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\saadb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\migrate-mongo\samples\undefined\migration.js'
```

I am running the command from VS code terminal. Is this right or should I run it from somewhere else

Comment: You probably configured your project wrong somewhere. The `undefined` should not be there, it should be a proper directory name, but without seeing your project it is hard to tell where it comes from.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `moduleSystem` property in your `migrate-mongo-config.js`

It can be `esm` or `commonjs`, depends on which one you using. More details here - https://github.com/seppevs/migrate-mongo/blob/49e6de971bc9581ce3a2321da2180a7877aff3a6/samples/esm/migrate-mongo-config.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code solved the problem:

```
npx migrate-mongo create blacklist_the_beatles
```

Comment: not sure why, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Seems very weird, buy I was able to solve the issue by manually creating "undefined" folder in the prompted path, and I also put there all files from commonjs folder.